# Default values of array

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I am curious. How are those undefined values trowed over here when I try to print them?

I thought that an undefined array has values equal to 0.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
// your code goes here

int log[][4];
int addOne=0;

for(int i=0;i<7;i++)
{
    log[addOne][0]=11+i;
    log[addOne][1]=11+i;
    //log[addOne][2]=11+i;
    log[addOne++][3]=11+i;
}

for(int i=0;i<11;i++)
{
printf("log[%d][0] = %d\n", i, log[i][0]);
printf("log[%d][1] = %d\n", i, log[i][1]);
printf("log[%d][2] = %d\n", i, log[i][2]);
printf("log[%d][3] = %d\n", i, log[i][3]);
}

return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
log[0][0] = 11
log[0][1] = 11
log[0][2] = 1
log[0][3] = 11
log[1][0] = 12
log[1][1] = 12
log[1][2] = -1217403463
log[1][3] = 12
log[2][0] = 13
log[2][1] = 13
log[2][2] = -1081953076
log[2][3] = 13
log[3][0] = 14
log[3][1] = 14
log[3][2] = -1081953088
log[3][3] = 14
log[4][0] = 15
log[4][1] = 15
log[4][2] = -1216726312
log[4][3] = 15
log[5][0] = 16
log[5][1] = 16
log[5][2] = -1219603196
log[5][3] = 16
log[6][0] = 17
log[6][1] = 17
log[6][2] = 6
log[6][3] = 17
log[7][0] = -1216729360
log[7][1] = -1216729468
log[7][2] = -1081952888
log[7][3] = -1217105850
log[8][0] = -1216726312
log[8][1] = -1216764868
log[8][2] = -1216758952
log[8][3] = 0
log[9][0] = -1217100393
log[9][1] = -1216548864
log[9][2] = -1216546512
log[9][3] = 1
log[10][0] = -1081952912
log[10][1] = -1216623457
log[10][2] = -1216546072
log[10][3] = -1217997256
```

Is there a way to initialize 0 value to every index?

Comment: Are you using C or C++? `int log[][4];` [should not even compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/725a5e6178a5253a) in C++.

Comment: It won't compile in C either.

Comment: @user3386109 explain why it won't compile in [tag:c]??? This `int log[4][]` surely wont compile.

Comment: @user3386109 Good to know.  Wasn't sure so I left it out.

Comment: @iharob: Hmm, did they add `namespace` to C? Good news ;-)

Comment: The term "uninitialised" should be hint enough. An "undefined array" cannot even be accessed, because it does not exist.

Comment: @iharob How to make this program to compile in c, excluing the C++ part? http://ideone.com/JyuX4M

Comment: @iharob You can't declare an array without specifying a size, or using an initializer. You *"fixed"* it in the first snippet in your answer by adding an initializer, but in the process created an array of size 1, i.e. `int log[1][4]`

Comment: @user3386109 Yes you are right, I see waht you mean because the size of the array would be imposible to determine. I normally never even think about that because of course it doesn't make sense. But I added a comment in my answer mentioning it.

Comment: You are all right, I didn't compile that like this. Actually I declared the size of array `int log[20][4];` in [online compiler](https://www.codechef.com/ide)
I thought the first array size do not need to have specified size. Now I see it do not have to be specified only when values are assigned and therefor compiler knows the size of an array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Very simple

```
int log[][4] = {{0}};
```

But then your code would be terribly wrong, because you didn't allocate enough space for so many values<sup>1</sup> and thus, it will invoke undefined behavior.

If you want that, you need

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(void)
{
    int values[11][4] = {{0}};
    int addOne = 0;

    for (int i = 0 ; i < 7 ; i++) {
        values[addOne][0] = 11 + i;
        values[addOne][1] = 11 + i;
        values[addOne++][3] = 11 + i;
    }

    for (int i = 0 ; i < 11 ; i++) {
        printf("values[%d][0] = %d\n", i, values[i][0]);
        printf("values[%d][1] = %d\n", i, values[i][1]);
        printf("values[%d][2] = %d\n", i, values[i][2]);
        printf("values[%d][3] = %d\n", i, values[i][3]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and don't use `log` as an identifier because it's the natural logarithm function from *math.h* header.

Uninitialized<sup>2</sup> values are not automatically initialized to `0` except if they are declared `static`, or when they are in the global scope. It is done that way for performance reasons, initializing the values to `0` to overwrite the zeroes takes unnecessary work and you should be thankful that you will only initialize the values luckily with the final value.

There is a function, in the *strings.h* header that can do this too but it's rarely useful for something other than `0` except, for characters arrays. That is because you can set any number of bytes, thus you can't set the value `1` to every element in an array of `int`s with such function for example, it is

```
void *memset(void *s, int c, size_t n);
```

despite the second parameter being an `int` it can only set bytes, exactly `n` bytes.

As important is to mention, that as comments on your question by @[user3386109](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3386109/user3386109) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39153135/default-values-of-array/39153159#comment65649983_39153135) and @[NathanOliver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4342498/nathanoliver) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39153135/default-values-of-array/39153159#comment65649710_39153135) pointed out you can't really do this

```
int values[][4];
```

because that way it would be impossible to know what the size of the array is. You should either specify the missing size or, add an initializer like I did at the beginning of this answer. This is as a result and of course, illegal syntax.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>*as it is it's a size 1 array of arrays of size 4*</sub>

<sup>2</sup><sub>*not undefined, that's a different thing*</sub>